# Bootstrap carousel shows items sliding out but not sliding in

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using a bootstrap carousel to display some data. The slide out animation displays correctly, however when a new carousel-item comes in it just appears rather than slide left behind the previous one.

My code is as follows.

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"
     data-interval="{{vm.carouselDelay}}"
     ng-if="vm.birthdays.length">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div ng-repeat="person in vm.birthdays"
            class="carousel-item event-card" ng-class="{active: person == vm.birthdays[0]}">

            <event-card person="person"></event-card>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

event card is just a div that shows the information.

For reasons out of my control I'm using jQuery version 1.9.1, however both Bootstrap and Popperjs are on their latest version. However I tried running a carousel in another project with jQuery 1.9.1 and it worked fine.

Comment: Mixing AngularJS with Bootstrap jQuery can be problematic. Consider using [uib-carousel](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#carousel) a Bootstrap component written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team

Comment: Been trying for a few hours now, but the slides are simply rendered one on top of the other rather than being hidden, I've pretty much copied the example code from the uib page.

Comment: I don't see the `uib-carousel` directive in your example.